# Is there an opposite of the date() function (for formatting?)

Tags: php

I know that there's `strtotime()`, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Say I have this: `date('l, F jS', $datetime)`

Would there be a function where I can tell it the format (`'l, F jS'`) and a string (for example: `Saturday, August 21st` And it will output a timestamp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be looking for [strptime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) or [date_parse_from_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php).

(You can use [mktime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to transform the output into an actual timestamp if that's what you really need)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) isn't what you are looking for? It will cater to your needs perfectly. Consider the below code. It works for the timestamp you describe and virtually all other date formats you can imagine.

```
echo strtotime(date('l, F jS'));
```